# Upload an .AVI file in Matlab and move it across the screen

Tags: matlab, avi

I am very new at Matlab and I just would like to know if Matlab allow us to upload swf files. 
If not, i know that it is possible to upload a movie (AVI for example). Could I upload a movie and move it to different points of the screen at a certain speed and motion while it's playing? Do I need an specific toolbox for it?

Thank yoooou !!!

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/277814

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15794-video2flv/content/flvplayer.swf

Comment: well, I need to program a picture (jpg) that moves across the screen at a certain speed. And do the same with a movie (AVI). So i just want to know if it's possible to do that with Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of doing this is to display the image/movie in an axes object and then move the axes within the containing figure.

```
f = figure();
a = axes('Units', 'Normalized', 'Position', [0 .5 .1 .1]);

while true
  pos = get(a,'Position');
  pos(1) = mod(pos(1) + .01, 1);
  set(a, 'Position', pos);
  pause(.01); 
  drawnow; 
end
```

To get this to work with a movie you'd need to draw the movie within the axes

Comment: ok. thanks. i'll probably give it a go with something easy first and then go for the movie...